# Clone table rows and change IDs of new rows in jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I have a table containing the following information:

```
<table id="Requirements">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <select id="Id.0" name="Id.0" onChange="changeTextBox();">...
        </td>
        <td>
            <select id="Comparator.0" name="Comparator.0" onChange="changeTextBox();">...
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" id="Integer.0" name="Integer.0"/>...
        </td>
        <td>
            <select id="Value.0" name="Value.0">...
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

and an add button.

```
<input type="button" id="addButton" value="Add" onClick="appendRow();"/>
```

I need the `appendRow()` function to not only clone the previous row, but change its id and name to Id.1, Id.2, Comparator.1, Comparator.2, etc.  Because some of the drop down menus have so many values, it isn't feasible to create one giant append statement to recreate each row.  How can I alter a clone's attributes upon creating it? Thanks!

Edit: The IDs must be in the .0, .1 format. This form posts to a URL that reads them as such

Edit 2: Code

```
function appendRow() {
    $("QualificationRequirements").append($("QualificationRequirements tr:last").clone());
}
```

No attempt to change IDs, just a simple clone function that I can't get to work.

Comment: Easier solution, wrap this all in a container of unique ID, ditch all those `.0` ending unique ID's and replace with a common class. Now clone the container and increment that ONE ID, and your done.

Comment: Did you try anything so far, show the code ?

Comment: Where is your html (including table), do you have `add` button in every row or what ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You may try this ([**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/LAECx/503/))

**HTML:**

```
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" id="table-data">
    <tr>
       <td>SelectOne</td>
       <td>Select two</td>
       <!-- More Headers -->
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <select id="Id.0" name="Id.0">...</select>
        </td>
        <!-- More tds -->
        <td><input type="button" class="addButton" value="Add" /></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**JS:**

```
$(function(){
    $("#table-data").on('click', 'input.addButton', function() {
        var $tr = $(this).closest('tr');
        var allTrs = $tr.closest('table').find('tr');
        var lastTr = allTrs[allTrs.length-1];
        var $clone = $(lastTr).clone();
        $clone.find('td').each(function(){
            var el = $(this).find(':first-child');
            var id = el.attr('id') || null;
            if(id) {
                var i = id.substr(id.length-1);
                var prefix = id.substr(0, (id.length-1));
                el.attr('id', prefix+(+i+1));
                el.attr('name', prefix+(+i+1));
            }
        });
        $clone.find('input:text').val('');
        $tr.closest('table').append($clone);
    });

    $("#table-data").on('change', 'select', function(){
        var val = $(this).val();
        $(this).closest('tr').find('input:text').val(val);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
function addTableRow(table) { 
     var $tr = $(table).find('tr:last').clone(); 
     $tr.find('input').attr('id', function(){ 
          var parts = this.id.match(/(\D+)(\d+)$/); 
          return parts[1] + ++parts[2]; 
     }); 
     $(table).append($tr); 
     return true; 
};
```